# Paraphrasing course titles on resume

Tags: cv

Under the Education section of my resume, I have relevant courses listed for a position I'm applying for. Some of the courses have titles that are vague and do not convey their relevance well. Is it acceptable to paraphrase the course title in a way that does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's sufficiently important for you to list the courses taken, and a transcript may be sent, then it's probably best to list the original course titles. Any summaries of the content should be placed as a comment afterward. For instance:

> Widgets and Doohickies (Whatchamacallit Theory).